# XmlDataProvider, XPath and ListBox

Tags: wpf, xpath, xmldataprovider

I've been playing with XamlPad. I thought I'd embed some XML into the XAML to give me a fake set of hierarchical data. I'm not having much joy. This compiles, but doesn't show the items in the list. (Edit: The hierarchical aspect is for later. For now I just want to get stuff appearing in a list).

```
    <Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Page.Resources>
      <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MyXmlData" XPath="ParentNode">
          <x:XData>
            <MyDoc>Wee
                <ParentNode>Hi</ParentNode>
                <ParentNode>Low</ParentNode>
            </MyDoc>
          </x:XData>
      </XmlDataProvider>  
  </Page.Resources>
  <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyXmlData}" ShowGridLines="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightGray">
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
  </Border>
</Page>
```

If you remove the XPath="ParentNode" from the XmlDataProvider, it adds the entire document, verbatim, to the listbox. I'd prefer to have two nodes in the Listbox, one for each ParentNode.

Answer (score 0):

Okie dokie, the solution was simple enough, I added an empty namespace to the xml and then did the xpaths as usual. Here's the solution.

```
    <Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Page.Resources>
      <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MyDataProvider" XPath="MyDoc">
          <x:XData>
            <MyDoc xmlns="">Wee
                <ParentNode>Hi</ParentNode>
                <ParentNode>Low</ParentNode>
            </MyDoc>
          </x:XData>
      </XmlDataProvider>  
  </Page.Resources>
  <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyDataProvider}" ShowGridLines="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}"  Background="LightGray">
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
  </Border>
</Page>
```